# WPF XAML: place Image near TextBlock but align text to center of row

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a similar structure in a WPF app:

```
<Grid Background="White">
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="1234567" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold" Height="25" TextAlignment="Center"/>
    <Line X1="0" Y1="0" X2="160" Y2="0" Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="2"/>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.3*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Image Width="25" Height="25" Grid.Column="0" Source="img.png" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="3456789" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold" Height="25" TextAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

This results in the following layout:

[image]

Is there any way to place the bottom text in the center of the row, so it's alignment would match with the text above?
Or is there a solution to place the image on top of the bottom row on the left side without column definitions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a single-cell grid with different alignments. You will run the risk of long text being under the image, and you will have to set a Width value on the StackPanel. See the `HorizontalAlignment` flag below:

```
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="3456789" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <Image Width="25" Height="25" Source="img.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
    </Grid>
```